# Video classification using many to many LSTM in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, lstm

I have to build a binary classifier to predict whether the input video contains an action or not.
The input to the model will be of shape: `[batch, frames, height, width, channel]`
Here, batch is number of videos, frames is number of images in that video (It's fixed for every video), height is number of rows in that image, width is number of columns in that image, and channel is RGB colors.
I found in Andrej Karpathy blog that many to many Recurrent Neural Network is best for this application: http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/

Thus, I need to implement this in TensorFlow: 
[image]

I learned how to implement LSTM using this tutorial: https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/07_lstm.py#L52
But, it is implementing many to one LSTM and predicting output and reducing loss using only last tensor: `outputs[-1]`
And, I want to predict output using many tensors (let say 4) and reduce loss using them.

Here's my implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn
import numpy as np

# Training Parameters
batch = 5 # number of examples
frames = time_step_size = 20
height = 60
width = 80
channel = 3

lstm_size = 240
num_classes = 2

# Creating random data

input_x = np.random.normal(size=[batch, frames, height, width, channel])
input_y = np.zeros((batch, num_classes))
B = np.ones(batch)
input_y[:,1] = B

X = tf.placeholder("float", [None, frames, height, width, channel], name='InputData')
Y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, num_classes], name='LabelData')

with tf.name_scope('Model'):
    XR = tf.reshape(X, [-1, height*width*channel]) # shape=(?, 14400)
    X_split3 = tf.split(XR, time_step_size, 0) # 20 tensors of shape=(?, 14400)

    lstm = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size, forget_bias=1.0, state_is_tuple=True)
    outputs, _states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm, X_split3, dtype=tf.float32) # 20 tensors of shape=(?, 240)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(outputs[-1], num_classes, name='logits') # shape=(?, 2)

prediction = tf.nn.softmax(logits)

# Define loss and optimizer
with tf.name_scope('Loss'):
    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits, labels=Y))

with tf.name_scope('optimizer'):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, use_locking=False, name='Adam')
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op)

# Evaluate model (with test logits, for dropout to be disabled)
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    logits_output = sess.run(logits, feed_dict={X: input_x})
    print(logits_output.shape) # shape=(5, 2)

    sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={X: input_x, Y: input_y})

    loss, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict={X: input_x, Y: input_y})
    print("Loss: ", loss) # loss:  1.46626135e-05
    print("Accuracy: ", acc) # Accuracy:  1.0
```

Problems: 
1. I need help to implement many to many LSTM and predict output after certain frames (let say 4), but, I am only using last tensor `outputs[-1]` to reduce loss. There are 20 tensors, one for each `frames` or `time_step_size`. If I transform every 5th tensor: `outputs[4], outputs[9], outputs[14], outputs[-1]`, I will get 4 logits. So, how I am going to reduce loss on all four of them? 
2. One more problem is, I have to implement binary classifier, but I only have video of action I want to identify. So, the `input_y` is one hot representation of labels in which 1st column is always 0 and 2nd column is always 1 (action I have to identify), and I don’t have any example video in which 1st column's value is 1. Do you think it will work? 
3. Why in above implement, in only one iteration the accuracy is 1?

Thanks

Comment: You should consider sequence-to-sequence model, like this https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq

Answer (score 2):

For 1., `Dense` takes any number of batch dimensions, so you should be able to transform into logits from all of the steps in one go (then likewise operate on a batch until you get a final loss for each step, then aggregate e.g. by taking the mean).

For 2. and 3., it seems like you need to find some negative examples. There's a literature on "positive and unlabeled (PU)" learning and "one-class classification" which may help.

Comment: By steps do you mean tensors (`outputs`)? I am transforming the last tensors (`outputs[-1]`) into logits using: `tf.layers.dense(outputs[-1], num_classes, name='logits')`. There are 20 tensors, one for each `frames` or `time_step_size`. If I transform every 5th tensor: `outputs[4], outputs[9], outputs[14], outputs[-1]`, I will get 4 logits. So, how I am going to reduce loss on all four of them? I'm not sure what do you mean by "operate on a batch until you get a final loss for each step, then aggregate e.g. by taking the mean". Could you please give some code to explain.